# I need to be able to redownload a document that was submitted onto my django website

Tags: python, django, file, download

I am a beginner with django. I am busy with a website where users can submit papers. Then reviewers (other users) as well as the users who submitted the papers should be able to download the submitted papers (for editing and scoring)? How do I make the possible? When the document is uploaded, it provides me with a link that is the file path to where it is stored. When i click on it, it only displays a 404 message , bacause obviously I dont have a webpage or URL with that file path. How do I solve this?

**UPDATE**

I have seen the `path()` function that django provides, but I'm not sure on where to use it?

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I have edited my views.py file to look like this

```
def returnDoc(request):
    # This function get the documents of all the users and the in the html displays only the logged in authors submitted papers.
    doc = Document.objects.all()
    user = RegUser.objects.all()
    status = user

    return render_to_response('user_profiles/profile.html', {'doc':doc, 'status':status}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def download_paper(request, paper_pk):
    # Document is the model with the FileField.
    paper = get_object_or_404(Document, pk=paper_pk)

    with paper.pdf_file_field.open("r") as fd:
        response = HttpResponse(fd.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % paper.pdf_file_field.title
        return response
```

Then my template looks as follows:

`

```
        <p class="well"> Here you should be able to see any information regarding your submitted papers, including any reviews that have been made on these papers
            and the status of your paper as "accepted" or "rejected". Please note that all decisions made are final. </p>           

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2> Paper Submissions </h2>

            <!-- Display an author's papers (if they have any -->
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Paper Title </th>
                        <th> Institution </th>
                        <th> Abstract </th>
                        <th> File </th>
                        <th> Reviews* </th>
                        <th> Avg. Score </th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

            <!-- Iterate through each element of the Document() model and output each element in a table cell-->
            {% for item in doc %}
                {% if request.user == item.author %}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ item.title }}</td>
                    <td> {{ item.institution }} </td>
                    <td> {{ item.abstract }} </td>
                    <td> <a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{item.file}}" target="_blank"> {{item.title}}</a></td>
                    <td> N.A </td>
                    <td> */10 </td>
                    <td> <a href="#"> Edit Paper </a> 
                </tr>

                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
```

`

I'm not sure if the `"{{MEDIA_URL}}{{item.file}}"` should be in there, because it just redirects me to the file path in the URL itself. Should I just take it out?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Secure" downloads of uploaded files are done through views. (The alternative is to have the web server serve all uploaded files with some prefix, just like you would serve any static files. The drawback of this is that you lose all access control over the files. Anyone can read them.)

Instead of rendering a template, you send the file to the client as a response. (Assuming you are using a [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield)). Example:

```
def download_paper(request, paper_pk):
     paper = get_object_or_404(Paper, pk=paper_pk) # get your model instance
     # also check permissions on paper, if necessary
     with paper.pdf_file_field.open("r") as fd:
         response = HttpResponse(fd.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
         response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % paper.pdf_file_field.name
         return response
```

Comment: I found a solution. My file field is stored in a data type file, thus it does not need to be opened. Also I could not use `with` as it requires `__exit__` and `__enter__` methods. replaced `with` with: `fd = paper.file`